# Is it not recommended to ask a question concerning the use of a specific framework/library?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, not-constructive

I am now trying to explore the whole new world of [CocoaPods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CocoaPods). There are just so many pods to choose from. I am wondering whether it is recommended to ask a question about a specific library/framework.

(Below is only an imaginary situation.)
For example, suppose I found a pod called `XYZ`, and I used it in my code. After messing around with it, I found out that something in the library seems to be crashing my app.

Is it recommended that I ask a question like "why is XYZ doing that..." or "What is the workaround..."?

I think it is not recommended, because few people might be using the library so the question might not be so constructive. Also, few people will be able to answer it.

Am I right? Or are there other reasons why this is not recommended?

Comment: Keep your question specific and reproducible. It should contain the information we need to reproduce the issue without just giving us your whole project. That means reproducing the issue in a minimal example. If you can do that, it doesn't matter whose code the problem is with, as long as we all can reproduce it.

Comment: I don't think *rarity* is a problem on SO. Not having anyone around that can answer it might be – but if your question is on topic, that is not a reason to reject it.

Comment: There's some cases where the Documentation site might be more suited, like questions about installing or using a library/framework in a certain way that isn't specific to a single issue.

Comment: I see 35k questions about NuGet from a quick search, (NuGet is the .NET equivalent of CocoaPods). As others have said, if it's a proper question, I think it's fine.

Comment: Thanks guys! I understand now!

Comment: "Your question shouldn't ask and answer." [Asking and answering is an acceptable practice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), however it does discourage/preclude other answers which might be useful or efficient/elegant.

Comment: For a particularly underused library/pod, you may even be better going directly to the source. Many of the libraries I've see today have Github links and issue lists there. You may even find you can contribute your own fix to the source and give back to the community yourself.

Comment: By definition, *every* CocoaPod library will have a publicly available repository...

Comment: @nhgrif I was speaking about libraries generally (no clue about pods - I'm not an iOS dev!), but that's good to know.

Comment: @theTinMan You're correct. I will add though that the answer shouldn't be in the_question_. The question should be phrased as an actual question, and the answer should be posted as an answer to that question.

Comment: Agreed, the answer and question are separate entities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is on topic for Stack Overflow if it covers:

> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

(https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Questions on CocoaPods seem entirely on topic:

> CocoaPods is a dependency manager for Swift and Objective-C Cocoa projects. It has over ten thousand libraries [...] CocoaPods is built with Ruby.

(https://cocoapods.org)

as long as your question is framed correctly – per the On Topic and How to ask a good question topics in the Help.

It is entirely possible that questions on a new, or, quite similar, an *old*, technology will not be immediately answered by someone. Possibly you are the very first to ask a question on a *specific* CocoaPod library ([4,289 questions, going back to 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+cocoapods), which is far less than the number of libraries it manages). As long as the question is within the realm of Practical Programming and is well stated, it is welcome.